# JavaScript: list files from http

Tags: javascript, http, frontend, client-side

Can i retrieve a list of files that are located in a URI (HTTP Server) from JavaScript?  I only find methods that rely in server side scripting (ie, get the list from a php that reads and outputs the file list accessing the filesystem)

Answer (score 0):

If you store that list in a single file or you know all the locations you want to check, you can use an [AJAX request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started) on the client side to make a HTTP request and subsequently load data from your own server.

If you are pulling data from a domain that differs from the one serving the page which runs the AJAX request, then you will run into a problem with your "Cross Origin Request" which will likely prevent you from implementing this feature.

Answer (score 0):

In general http not pass files. it pass information.
You send request and receive answer.

For example:

if you go to the site:

```
http://www.example.com/index.html
```

the server receive request with route and it decide what to do with it.
The server can response with index.html file but it can response also with a picture file or another information.
if you want you can read the http protocol
https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616
or in wikipedia

If you want you can save all your data in one json file and request this information from the server. Another way is to use ftp..

Comment: So, when i access a URL without any html file and i see a list of files inside that physical directory, how can the browser display the file and folder list? Can i do this programatically wit javascript without any access to any html or server side script?

Comment: This is the server that send you the list of file. If that what the server do you can go to this URL and see the list of file. This is depend on the server. if the server sends you the list of file, so you can send ajax request to the server and receive this list. BUT this is not HTTP regular behaviour

Comment: @GrupoICCSolucionesProfesion Do you still have a problem. If not please close the question..